# How to split my NDK project into lib and app

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have an NDK-based project (written mostly on C++) and I want to split its sources into two parts: "lib" (to be shared with other projects) and "app" (files specific to current project).

Now my Android.mk looks as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := MyProj

MY_LIB_SOURCES := \
libfile1.cpp \
libfile2.cpp

MY_APP_SOURCES := \
appfile1.cpp \
appfile2.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_LIB_SOURCES)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_APP_SOURCES)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

The only reason for splitting is that I want to add/remove lib source file once, because now I have to change Android.mk for all projects which need sources from `MY_LIB_SOURCES`.

Do I have to create a separate project that would produce a shared library? Or should it be a static library? Or maybe it's possible to just `#include` somehow file that enumerates `MY_LIB_SOURCES` into Android.mk of each app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually create a separate folder for library sources, e.g.

```
project
  jni
    appfile1.cpp
    appfile2.cpp
    Android.mk (1)

my_lib
  libfile1.cpp
  libfile2.cpp
  Android.mk   (2)
```

This is the first (*application*) **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := MyProj

MY_APP_SOURCES := \
appfile1.cpp \
appfile2.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_APP_SOURCES)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += MyLib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../my_lib/Android.mk
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

This is the second (*library*) **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := MyLib

MY_LIB_SOURCES := \
libfile1.cpp \
libfile2.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_LIB_SOURCES)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Using the **Andorid.mk** name for **MyLib** is by convention; you could use some other file name, and change the *include* statement (line 17 of the first **Android.mk** file) accordingly.

You could also use the same [`$(call import-module)`](http://brian.io/android-ndk-r10c-docs/Programmers_Guide/html/md_4__additional__info__i_m_p_o_r_t-_m_o_d_u_l_e.html) syntax, like

```
$(call import-module,my_lib)
```

But to do so, you must provide a **NDK_MODULE_PATH** environment variable that includes **$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../**.

Your library will be rebuilt anew for each app (project) that includes it - either with the first naïve **include** method, or with [`$(call import-module)`](http://brian.io/android-ndk-r10c-docs/Programmers_Guide/html/md_4__additional__info__i_m_p_o_r_t-_m_o_d_u_l_e.html) method. You can provide a [prebuilt](http://brian.io/android-ndk-r10c-docs/Programmers_Guide/html/md_3__key__topics__libraries__p_r_e_b_u_i_l_t_s.html) static library, but this is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

You must divide your android.mk in two sections:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

## The lib ##
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := my_lib

SRC_LIB := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SRC_LIB:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

## The App ##
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := my_app
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    appfile1.cpp \
    appfile2.cpp

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := my_lib
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

If you want static library you have only to change `include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)` to `include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)` and `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := my_lib` to `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += my_lib`

Comment: If I extend mylib with libfile3.cpp then I would have to add libfile3.cpp into all Android.mk of all apps which utilize the lib. Such copy-pasting is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: You can add all files from a path, so if you add a file in the path, this file will be included in your project, you have only to use wildcard, I edited my post.